# How do i delete country from my mailing label format

Tags: mailing, address-labels

How do i delete country (United States) from my mailing label format.
I can't seem to print mailing labels without United States on the last line and the USPS doesn't want that.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

- If you are based in the United States, go to **Administer > Localization > Address Settings**.  Set *Hide Country in Mailing Labels when same as domain country* to **Yes**.  You can double-check that CiviCRM thinks you're US-based by going to **Administer menu > Communications > Organization Address and Contact Info** and checking the *Country* field under *Default Organization Address*.
- If you are NOT based in the United States, go to **Administer > Localization > Address Settings**.  Remove **{contact.country}** from the bottom of the *Mailing Label* field.  Note that this removes country for ALL mailings.
- If you need something more fine-grained (e.g. you're not US-based, but need to remove country from mailings sent to the US), install my extension [com.megaphonetech.addressl10n](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.addressl10n).  This will let you do per-country mailing label formats.

Comment: "There are two ways:  1), 2), 3)" :-)